# Can't search "once" in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm doing a text search in mongodb like this:

```
db.getCollection('textsearches').find({"$text" : {"$search" : "once"}})
```

This gives me no results. When I try to modify the search to something like this:

```
db.getCollection('textsearches').find({"$text" : {"$search" : "once upon"}});
```

it gives me the correct result where there is clearly a field with the phrase "once upon" in it. Why does it not work with the keyword "once" ? Does this have anything to do with how stemming works in mongodb?

Comment: What happens if you search for "\"once upon\"" or "-once upon"?

Comment: I also suspect the engine is doing exact matches.

Comment: `"\"once upon\""`  results in exact match of the phrase, returning only 1 matching result. `"-once upon"` returns all such documents which contain either of the words `(once, upon, once upon)`

Comment: Hmm. What if you specify `{$search : "once upon", $language: "none"}`

Comment: Same result as before.

Comment: No more ideas. Double check your data and queries. Remember that it looks for "once" OR "upon" with the query you showed. Hopefully you get it sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**docs**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words)

> MongoDB supports text search for various languages. text indexes drop
>   language-specific [**stop words**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt) (e.g. in English, the, an, a, and, etc.)
>   and use simple language-specific suffix stemming. For a list of the
>   supported languages, see Text Search Languages.
>
> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text index uses
>   simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.

So you can `createIndex` by specifying the `default_language` to `none`

```
db.getCollection("textsearches").createIndex(
  { "field" : "text" },
  { "default_language": "none" }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to delete and re-create the index. Once I did that, I started getting results for  "once" keyword as well.